# Tool for find & replace text in file - input from external file

Tags: windows, text-processing

I'm creating an HTML template that will be used by a user who isn't a programmer.
The HTML template has placeholders in which the user has to insert text.

I would like to offer that user a tool that accepts:

- a list of placeholders (preferably from a file)
- a list of replacements for placeholders (preferably from a file)
- the document in which to do the replacement (in my case, the above HTML template)

I downloaded a tool that comes very close to what I want called [Replace Text](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/bkreplace.html):

[image]

I just can't get it to work...

**Note:** our project does require a static HTML file, as the output is to be sent in a newsletter, so dynamic template engines for web servers will not do.

Comment: Shalom Lea, wouldn't it be more practical to use a web-based template engine, which you then could feed e.g. via a CSV file (having two columns, placeholder and replacement), or even database driven? That's how it's practiced with many projects. There exist plenty of template engines for different frameworks (PHP, Pearl, Python, …). It's of course different if you *require* static HTML files on your server.

Comment: Hi @Izzy, thank you. Actually our project does require a static HTML file, as the output is to be sent in a newsletter.

Comment: OK, then I'm out. Ive integrated that fact with your question directly, so it won't be missed by potential answerers. Good luck!